# Trouble with graphics in a Java JPanel, but it works in a frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, tic-tac-toe

I'm new to this and am using the book Big Java by Cay Hortsmann to learn. For one of the early projects, I'm making a tic-tac-toe game with a GUI, but I'm having trouble getting the board to show up on a JPanel. It shows up fine just in the frame, but since I want to add buttons, I try to put the board in a JPanel and then add the JPanel to the frame. Unfortunately, this isn't working. I'd appreciate any feedback you can give:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class TicTacToePlayer {

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;

    private int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        // create board
        final LinesComponent boardLines = new LinesComponent();     
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(boardLines);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;


public class LinesComponent extends JComponent {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Lines boardLines = new Lines();
        boardLines.draw(g2);
    }

}
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;


public class Lines extends JComponent {
    public Lines() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        Line2D.Double leftVertLine = new Line2D.Double(150, 50, 150, 350);
        Line2D.Double rightVertLine = new Line2D.Double(250, 50, 250, 350);
        Line2D.Double topHorizLine = new Line2D.Double(50, 150, 350, 150);
        Line2D.Double bottomHorizLine = new Line2D.Double(50, 250, 350, 250);
        g2.draw(leftVertLine);
        g2.draw(rightVertLine);
        g2.draw(topHorizLine);
        g2.draw(bottomHorizLine);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets start with the obvious...

- `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` which honours the `preferredSize` of the components that are added to it.  `JComponent` has a default size of `0x0`, meaning that when you add `boardLines` to it, it is effectivly made invisible and never painted.  You can create this by using a `BorderLayout` on `panel`, for example `JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());`
- While technically not required, it's always good pratice to call `super.paintComponent` when performing custom painting
- You should not be creating short lived objects within `paintComponent`, especially when there state doesn't change in any way (that is, the result of creating a new instance is the same as it was for the previous instance you created).  `paintComponent` can be called repeatedly and in short order, this could an unnecessary strain on your system
- `Lines` doesn't need to extend from `JComponent`, seriously, it's just not doing anything...
- Use `pack` instead of `setSize` on `JFrame`, it will make life a lot easier...
- Swing UI's should be created and manipulated on from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

As an example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TicTacToePlayer {

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;

    private int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TicTacToePlayer();
    }

    public TicTacToePlayer() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                // create board
                final LinesComponent boardLines = new LinesComponent();
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                panel.add(boardLines);
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class LinesComponent extends JComponent {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            draw(g2);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
            Line2D.Double leftVertLine = new Line2D.Double(150, 50, 150, 350);
            Line2D.Double rightVertLine = new Line2D.Double(250, 50, 250, 350);
            Line2D.Double topHorizLine = new Line2D.Double(50, 150, 350, 150);
            Line2D.Double bottomHorizLine = new Line2D.Double(50, 250, 350, 250);
            g2.draw(leftVertLine);
            g2.draw(rightVertLine);
            g2.draw(topHorizLine);
            g2.draw(bottomHorizLine);
        }
    }
}
```

You should considering having a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Answer (score 2):

The default layout manager for a panel is a `FlowLayout` which arranges elements from left-to-right. Since you want the grid to appear in the main view, you may consider using a different layout manager such as a `BorderLayout`. If you use a `BorderLayout`, you can place the grid into the center region such that grid fills up the main view:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class TicTacToePlayer {

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;

    private int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

                // create board
                final LinesComponent boardLines = new LinesComponent();
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
                panel.add(boardLines, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
                frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

To add buttons to the window while using a `BorderLayout`, you can add the buttons to another `JPanel` and add that panel to the `BorderLayout` in one of the other regions (ie: `BorderLayout.NORTH`, `BorderLayout.SOUTH`, etc.).

Also, note that in the above corrected code that the Swing GUI code is placed in the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). You should never run any Swing code outside of the EDT because most Swing object methods are not thread safe.

For more information about layout managers, take a read at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).